# How to check if any property of a ViewModel has been filled

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, viewmodel

I have a ViewModel which contains properties that can **optionally** be filled from the user of my web application (e.g. first name, last name, e-mail, date of birth etc). These properties include several types like string, bool int, decimal, double, DateTime. All these types can be both nullable and non-nullable in the ViewModel.

If at least 1 of these properties has been filled in, then I have to create a database record. Do you have any idea for a way to check if any of these optional values has been filled?

Comment: Do you implemenet `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: @arcticwhite no I'm not implementing it. This is just a simple check I have to do once i post the form to the server.

Comment: @arcticwhite it's an ASP.NET Core application, so it's MVC-based.

Comment: Since you mention that your viewmodel can have non-nullables; how are you deciding if a non-nullable field is filled in? Are you assuming that if the field matches the default value for its type, that it is therefore not filled in?

Answer (score 0):

By convention, primitive data types are required. You can make the properties nullable which are primitive like int, double, DateTime vs. Then:

```
PropertyInfo[] infos = yourObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperties();            
int count = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < infos.Length; i++)
{
    if(infos[i].PropertyType == typeof(string))
    {
        string stringValue = infos[i].GetValue(yourObjectInstance).ToString().Trim();

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(body))
        {
            count++;
        }

        continue;
    }

    if(infos[i].GetValue(yourObjectInstance) != null)
    {                    
        count++;
    }
}

if(count == 0)
{
    // Handle error
}

// Create record
```

Comment: I tried it out right now, but the check against null doesn't work as expected for empty strings. My goal is that also empty strings are considered as null (or more precisely are considered as not-filled in)

Comment: what is the purpose of the check if(infos[i].Name == "YourStringPropertyName") ? I don't see any need to check/compare the name of a property so far.

Comment: It was checking only for one property which it's type is string and name is YourStringPropertyName. I've changed again for checking multiple string properties, try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this code, pass your viewmodel, then count how much fields are not null, if the return **value>0**, then you can implement your Db work.

```
public int MethodToCheckNotNull(ViewModel obj)
{
        int i = 0;
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(obj).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            if (property.GetValue(obj) != null)
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
        return i;
 }
```